# 4/0 AL ok for 24kw generator?

Tags: wiring, generator

I have a generator, which needs wire, it’s a generac 24KW gen, with a 200 amp ATS, is it okay if I use 4/0,4/0,4/0,2/0 AL Wire ?

Answer (score 3):

Some are surprised by this fact: [the US is a 240V country](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4).  Anything over about 20A is pretty much implied to be 240V.  So a 24,000 watt supply is going to be 100 amps, not 200 amps.

So from the generator to the transfer switch, 1 AWG will suffice as discussed by Ecnerwal. However, I don't figure you bought a 200A transfer switch *for chuckles*. I have to imagine that like most modern US homes you have 200 amp service (that's 48 kW). For that, you will need honest 200A on the other two legs of the transfer switch - from utility to transfer switch, and transfer switch to loads.

200 amp wire  will indeed need to be 250 kcmil (4/0 will suffice if the utility provided service is 200A and it serves a dwelling).

If your logic is "well I'm buying 4/0 *anyway* for those other two legs, just buy a bit more" - sure, I see that.  Or for future expansion.  However you may have trouble getting 4/0 to fit on equipment made for 100A.

At 240V, 150' isn't quite far enough to start worrying about voltage drop.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you *can* if it makes you *happy,* but given the generator is only 100A, regardless of the size of the transfer switch, the generator part of the wiring can be **much** smaller - 1 or 1/0 AWG Aluminum depending if you're constrained to 60°C or 75°C by your terminal ratings and wiring method.

If you ae running it some absurd distance you have not mentioned and want larger wire for voltage drop reasons, sure, fine...

Or perhaps you have enough 4/0 sitting around collecting dust - again, sure, fine.

Comment: Check the lugs on the generator to see if it will accept 4/0. If you really want to use 4/0 you may have to splice to smaller wires at the genset.  Ecnerwal:   I was going to say the same thing about if the OP just happened to have the 4/0 laying around.   At any rate, if he's buying wire,  he should take your suggestion.  BTW I HATE wrestling with 4/0 AL.   ...UV

Comment: Yes it’s 150 ft of wire run ,